# Reference error - Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, navigation

I'm working on mobile filters. There are a few buttons. After click every button receive class `active-filter-btns`. I did everything but during Firefox tests I got error `ReferenceError: event is not defined`. Chrome and Safari work correctly. 
Any ideas why Mozilla see error and how to fix it? Or maybe different way to add `active class`?

HTML:

```
 <div id="search-btns" class="filter-btns">
        <button id="filter-btn-all" class="filter-btn" onclick="Project.Search.selectCategory(this.id)">A - Z</button>
        <button id="filter-btn-provider" class="filter-btn" onclick="Project.Search.selectCategory(this.id)">Providers</button>
        <button id="filter-btn-jackpot" class="filter-btn" onclick="Project.Search.selectCategory(this.id)">Jackpot</button>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
Project.Search.selectCategory = function(event) {
  if(event.target.classList.contains('active-filter-btns')){
    this.showCategories();
  } else {
    switch(e) {
      case "filter-btn-all": 
        this.showAllGames();
        break;
      case "filter-btn-provider":
        this.showProviders();
        break;
      case "filter-btn-jackpot":
        this.showJackpotGames();
        break;
    }
  }

  if (!event.target.classList.contains('filter-btn'))
    return;

  event.target.classList.toggle('active-filter-btns');

  let links = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn'); 
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    if (links[i] === event.target)
      continue;
    links[i].classList.remove('active-filter-btns');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,in firefox,you have to pass the event object.

```js
Project.Search.selectCategory = function(event) {
   if(event.target.classList.contains('active-filter-btns')){
    this.showCategories();
 } else {
     switch(event.target.id) {
        case "filter-btn-all": 
            this.showAllGames();
            break;
        case "filter-btn-provider":
            this.showProviders();
            break;
        case "filter-btn-jackpot":
            this.showJackpotGames();
            break;
    }
}

if (!event.target.classList.contains('filter-btn')) {
    return;
}

event.target.classList.toggle('active-filter-btns');

let links = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-btn'); 
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i] === event.target) {
            continue;
        }
    links[i].classList.remove('active-filter-btns');
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="search-btns" class="filter-btns">
        <button id="filter-btn-all" class="filter-btn" onclick="Project.Search.selectCategory(event)">A - Z</button>
        <button id="filter-btn-provider" class="filter-btn" onclick="Project.Search.selectCategory(event)">Providers</button>
        <button id="filter-btn-jackpot" class="filter-btn" onclick="Project.Search.selectCategory(event)">Jackpot</button>
 </div>
```

the reason can be showed by this demo:you have to pass the event as parameter in the onclick

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    
</head>

<body>
    <span id="counter" onclick="test(this.id,event)">1,234,567.15</span>
</body>
<script>
function test(event) {
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    console.log(arguments[1]);
}
</script>

</html>
```

if you didn't pass,it will be undefined,like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title><!-- 
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body>
    <span id="counter" onclick="test(this.id)">1,234,567.15</span>
</body>
<script>
function test(event) {
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    console.log(event);//counter,because you pass id 'counter' ,you didn't pass event
}
</script>

</html>
```